# Is there a possibility to run code before Excel triggers calculation?

Tags: office-js, excel-addins

I created a custom function with office-js which returns a dynamic array containing number values as well as error values (#N/A). Because of the error values, Excel triggers recalculation of the custom function every time the workbook is opened (as long as #N/A values are returned).

Is there a possibility to prevent Excel from triggering the recalculation only for my custom function or is there a possibility to run code before Excel triggers the recalculation, so that I can read the old values before they are updated?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking :)

- You can set the calculation mode to manual to prevent that. We don't have before events in the javascript world as our events and apis are designed to fire asynchronously which gives users more responsiveness while your code is running.
- I'd also ensure your function is not tagged as volatile (Which has the behavior of refreshing each time).

In terms of reading the old values before they are updated, I'm curious to learn about your scenario, if you're up for it. Here's a good way to get in touch with us on the product team.  If you can, within Excel, please follow these instructions and send us a frown: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-do-i-give-feedback-on-microsoft-office-2b102d44-b43f-4dd2-9ff4-23cf144cfb11

- In the description, please be sure to indicated  "To: Office Platform team: Following up on stackoverflow question 64061871".  Please also let me know when submitted and I will be able to get your contact info, and can reach out to setup a demo with our product team.

thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)
I already considered to set the calculation mode to manual, but because of other functionality in my Excel sheet the calculation mode has to be automatic.

The functionality to read the old values before they are updated is only considered as a workaround, if it is not possible to prevent the recalculation when the workbook opens.
The problem I have is that on recalculation the data that gets back to the Excel sheet can change.

Comment: Because of that I would like to fetch the correct data from Excel before recalculation and then determine by a flag on the custom function if I write back the old values or can fetch new data.